# Selichos during Beis HaMikdash?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, provenance, selichot, authorship

1. a) When were the *tefillos* of *Selichos* instituted or composed? 
   b) Who composed them?
2. When were they first said?
3. Did they say *selichos* in the times of the *Beis HaMikdash* ?

Comment: http://www.myjewishlearning.com/holidays/Jewish_Holidays/Rosh_Hashanah/High_Holidays/Selichot.shtml